# Mind Maps for teaching Mathematics

Tags: soft-question, education

Has anyone used [Mind Maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_map) to teach advanced mathematical topics?

If so, how did it work, was it useful or a waste of time?

Thanks for any insights.

Regards -A

Comment: mind maps are a waste of time in general.

Comment: Nice question! I don't think they're necessarily a waste of time...I'll look into it... ;-) +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks. I am actually very interesting if anyone is doing this. We have successfully used them in other areas and I think it may be possible for organizing math too, including for taxonomies of entire subjects or classifications. Regards

Comment: I'm amazed there is no answer to this question. I personally have never used a mind map. But wikipedia claims, "Cunningham (2005) conducted a user study in which 80% of the students thought "mindmapping helped them understand concepts and ideas in science."" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_map#Effectiveness

I imagine they are more useful for people who are weaker at maths in general ?